# how to stop repetition in jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a image library and my code contains much repetition. Does anyone of you have an idea on how to make this work better?

Here is a exemple of the code

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="buttoncont">
        <button id="all" type="button">All</button>
        <button id="dog" type="button">Dog</button>
        <button id="cat" type="button">Cat</button>
    </div>
    <img class="cat_img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" />
    <img class="dog_img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg" />
</div>
```

JS

```
 $("#cat").click(function () {
     $("img.dog_img").hide();
     $("img.cat_img").show();
 });
 $("#dog").click(function () {
     $("img.cat_img").hide();
     $("img.dog_img").show();
 });
 $("#all").click(function () {
     $(".cat_img, .dog_img").show();

 });
```

Comment: i do not see any repetition. what do you think is repeating?

Comment: use `toggle()` in stead of `hide()` and `show()` toggle detects wether it needs to be shown or hidden.

Comment: Hey, whats the logic for having a button called "All" that select the two, assuming that when you select one the other is unselected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this

Keep the html as you have it.

```
$(".toggle").click( 
    function() {
        $("."+ $(this).attr('id') + "_img").toggle() 
    }
);

$("#all").click( 
    function() { 
        $("img[class$='_img']").show() 
    }
);
```

This way you can add as many images and buttons as you want without modifying your javascript

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zcw54/)

Comment: if he keeps the html he will not have ".toogle" class :p

Answer (score 1):

```
 function toggleImages(e){
  $('img').hide();
  $('img.'+e.target.id+'_img').show();
 }

 $("#cat").click(toggleImages);
 $("#dog").click(toggleImages);
 $("#all").click(function () {
     $(".cat_img, .dog_img").show();

 });
```

---

```
  <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="buttoncont">
          <button id="all" type="button">All</button>
          <button id="dog" type="button">Dog</button>
          <button id="cat" type="button">Cat</button>
      </div>
      <img class="cat_img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" />
      <img class="dog_img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg" />
  </div>
```

Comment: problem with that is when both are visible, the toggle will hide both /show both on every click

Comment: I made a little improvement to even further reduce code repetition. Please let me know if you have any objections to my changes :)

Comment: @Anton - I think it would be safe to assume that one is not displayed from the beginning since we are talking about toggling the display. But that is still a good observation.

Comment: Both will be displayed if you click #all @Lix

Comment: this way... the `#cat` needs to initiate hidden and the dog showing.. or the opposite.

Comment: @Lix if you click on All then the Cat and Dog buttons will break with this solution.

Comment: @Liam - It's right there in the code... `toggleImages` is a function.

Comment: Ignore me, I missed it.

Comment: I agree this code will break when all button is clicked. i'm fixing it

Comment: @JamesDonnelly, I don't see it, why?

Answer (score 1):

**First: you need to set a default selected to make the Toggle work as expected.**

Use CSS Classes to make the divs into one group(class) and bind the event to it, see the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="buttoncont">
        <button id="all" type="button">All</button>
        <button class=toggle id="dog" type="button">Dog</button>
        <button class=toggle id="cat" type="button">Cat</button>
    </div>
    <img class="cat_img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" />
    <img class="dog_img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg" />
</div>
```

And on the Javascript Code, do a function to do it for you and use jQuery Toggle:

```
 function toggleImg(){
   $('img.dog_img').toggle();
   $('img.cat_img').toggle();
 }
 $(".toggle").click(function () {
   toggleImg();
 });
 $("#all").click(function () {
   $(".cat_img, .dog_img").show();
 });
```

But on the `onLoad` event of your page `Toggle` one of they indivually to make it the default selected, this way `Toggling` the two, always only one will be visible.

```
$('html').ready(function(){    
  $('img.cat_img').toggle();
});
```

Comment: This will show or hide both images when any button is pushed. (assuming they both start visible, dog/cat buttons will hide both)

Comment: Even with a default, using Toggle, I can click cat twice and see a dog.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the surrounding HTML, you may have to modify this.  But with JUST the HTML you've shared, you can do this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  $('img').hide();
  $("." + this.id + "_img").show();

  //Workaround for '#all'
  if( this.id === 'all' ){
    $('img').show();
  }
});
```

You could also modify your HTML to take advantage of the `data-` attribute:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="buttoncont">
        <button data-show="dog, cat" type="button">All</button>
        <button data-show="dog" type="button">Dog</button>
        <button data-show="cat" type="button">Cat</button>
    </div>
    <img class="cat_img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/Turkish_Van_Cat.jpg" />
    <img class="dog_img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/26/YellowLabradorLooking_new.jpg" />
</div>
```

JS (untested, but should work):

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(){
  var arrShow = this.getAttribute('data-show').split(/\s*,\s*/);

  $('img').hide();

  for( var i = arrShow.length; i-- > 0; ){
    $('.' + arrShow[i] + '_img').show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
$('#buttoncont button').click(function(){
    if(this.id=='all'){
        $('img').show();
    }else{
        $('img').hide().filter('.'+ this.id +'_img').show();
    }
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/b65EL/

Answer (score 0):

An idea

```
$("#all").click(function(){
  $(".cat_img, .dog_img").show();
}
$("#dog, #cat").click(function(){
  $("img."+this.id+"_img").toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ID attributes on the buttons unless you need them for something else.

Add a custom attribute to the buttons, such as:

```
<button id="cat" type="button" image-clicker="cat_img">Cat</button>
```

Then add this jquery to the page (I didn't test this so you may have to fix minor issues with it):

```
$(function(){
  $("[image-clicker]").each(function(){
    var buttonClicked = $(this);
    var targetID = buttonClicked.attr("image-clicker");
    var targetElement = $("#"+targetID);

    $(this).click(function(){
       // hide other images
       $("[image-clicker]").hide();
       targetElement.show();
    });
 };
```

});